# Laravel TypeError in many to many relationship

Tags: laravel

I have 3 models: Order, Products, OrderProducts:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ]; 

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(OrderProduct::class);
    }
}

class Products extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'link', 'buyprice', 'sellprice','weight',
    ]; 

    public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(OrderProduct::class);
    }
}

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id', 'product_id',
    ];     

    public function orders() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class);
    }

}
```

When i view a specific Order i want to display all associated products, which i try to retrieve like this in my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    //$products = Products::all();
    $order = Order::where('id',$id)->first();

    $orderList = $order->products();
    
    return $orderList;
    
}
```

The error i get it:

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in D:\laravel\pricing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72
```

How can i get collection of all products for a specific order?

Comment: try changing  $orderList = $order->products(); to  $orderList = $order->products()->get();

Comment: Probbly you need to change `this->belongsToMany(OrderProduct::class);` to `this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_products');`

Comment: @sta That isn't the default naming convention is it? Shouldn't it be `order_product`? Also the error points to the issue being the fact that the OP is returning a query builder object as the response. So they need to either do `return $order->product` or follow John's suggestion.

Comment: My bad with bad naming, had to redo some naming, and it worked now, thanks